# UK - Cooling off period after signing rental contract

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, rent

I'm in process to sign a contract for a flat. The conditions written are the following: *one year* with no break clause.

Before signing I'm trying to find out the following information.

- Is there in UK a cooling off period after the signature of a rental contract to break it? (e.g., 1 week)
- Is there a way to break it before the 1 year is over? Is mutual agreement the only way?

Comment: If you don't like the fact there is no clause to break the lease, tell him before hand and add it.

Comment: I've tried, but it's the only form of contract offered, so I'm thinking before signing.

Comment: Sorry they won't do it for you. You should prob find somewhere else to live then.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not break the lease early without an agreement or their would be no reason to have a lease. You would just pay by the month.

https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/private_renting/how_tenants_can_end_a_fixed_term_tenancy

If you aren't sure you want to live there for the whole term of the lease you should probably keep looking.

Comment: Thank you, This answers the second question. What about the first?

Comment: It answers both, no, you can't get out of the lease without agreement.